# Event-driven asynchronous callbacks of Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am reading The Node Beginner Book. In the chapter Event-driven asynchronous callbacks, the author gives an example to illustrate the idea of asynchronous callbacks. The code example is like:

```
var result = database.query("SELECT * FROM hugetable");
console.log("Hello World");
```

After adding a callback function to database.query, the code becomes asynchronous:

```
database.query("SELECT * FROM hugetable", function(rows) {
    var result = rows;
});
console.log("Hello World");
```

My question is why the database.query() function becomes asynchronous simply after adding a callback function.
I have no experience with Javascript and JQuery before, that might be the reason I cannot understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many functions in node.js that have both an asynchronous flavor and a synchronous flavor.  For example, there are two ways to read the contents of a file ([docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback)):

```
//asynchronous
fs.readFile("filename.txt", function(err, data) {

});

//synchronous
var data = fs.readFileSync("filename.txt");
```

The example the author provides does in fact look somewhat confusing, but its possible that the `database.query` makes an asynchronous call depending on whether a `callback` is passed in as the second argument.

For example, it could be implemented something like this:

```
function query(queryString, callback) {
  if(callback !== undefined) {
    queryInternal(queryString, callback);
    return;
  }
  else {
    return queryInternalSync(queryString);
  }
}
```

In general, I think the convention is that a `function` is either `asynchronous` or `synchronous` (not both) so your intuition is right.

Note that in the `synchronous` case, `console.log` will be executed after `result` has the queried contents whereas in the `asynchronous` case, `console.log` will be executed as soon as `query` function returns and before `callback` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

`Asynchronously` means it don't `waits` for the `response` and go to the next statements
to be executed

In your second example the callback function handles your response while executing this,
it doesn't waits and `console.log("Hello World");` shows the `output` in `console`.

Read this:

- http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/
- http://nodemanual.org/latest/nodejs_dev_guide/writing_asynchronous_code.html
- http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice